# Android Access to raw json for CustomObject

Tags: android, json, quickblox

I have created a Custom object in the Quickblox console, I can retrieve the objects but now need access to the raw JSON object.

I can rebuild the object manually iterating through the fields and was hoping I could just reference and raw JSON directly saving processing time and power for large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Each result has **result.getRawBody()**  method, hope this help

Comment: Thanks, this is a little lower than I expected but will suite my needs.